# Parameters in webservice SOAP

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I started messing with webservice via SOAP shortly and I have a question, I need to send the following information in a request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.senior.com.br">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:AniversariantesMes>
         <user>usuario</user>
         <password>senha</password>
         <encryption>0</encryption>
         <parameters>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <competencia>01/01/2020</competencia>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <flowInstanceID>?</flowInstanceID>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <flowName>?</flowName>
         </parameters>
      </ser:AniversariantesMes>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I am trying to do with the code below:

```
$client = new SoapClient('link do soap');

$function = 'AniversariantesMes';

$parameters = [
    'competencia' => '01/01/2020',
];

$arguments = array('AniversariantesMes' => array(
                        'user'          =>  'senior',
                        'password'      =>  'senior',
                        'encryption'    =>  0,
                        'parameters'    =>  $parameters,
));

print_r($arguments);

$options = array('location' => 'link');

$result  = $client -> __soapCall($function,$arguments,$options);

print_r($result);
```

the code does not consider 'Competencia' and brings the default values (I tested the filters on SoapUI and there when passing the 'Competencia' 01/01/2020 he filters the January birthdays)

Comment: When using `var_dump($client->__getFunctions());` the code return: `string(145) "treinamentoAniversariantesMesOut AniversariantesMes(string $user, string $password, int $encryption, treinamentoAniversariantesMesIn $parameters)"` i believe 
I believe I should pass the "treinamentoAniversariantesMesIn " but I don't know how

Answer (score 2):

Would you please test below function in your $parameters ?

> ```
> function SoapVar($key , $value)
> {
>     return new SoapVar("<".$key.">".$value."</".$key.">", XSD_ANYXML, null, null, null);
> }
> $parameters = [SoapVar( 'competencia' ,  '02/01/2020')];
> ```

Hope to be useful.

Comment: When `using var_dump($client->__getFunctions());` the code return: `string(145) "treinamentoAniversariantesMesOut AniversariantesMes(string $user, string $password, int $encryption, treinamentoAniversariantesMesIn $parameters)" i believe I believe I should pass the "treinamentoAniversariantesMesIn "` but I don't know how